# Componente DatePicker API no es consistente con la selección de fechas

Tags: html, jquery-datepicker

Tengo un formulario en HTML y javascript cuya funcionalidad principal es almacenar información (texto) en una lista de SharePoint Online *(Office 365)*; así como la actualización de la información *tomando como parámetro el ID enviado por `QueryString`*.

El formulario en HTML cuenta con 4 inputs pre-cargados con la [API DatePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) que ofrece JQuery.

**El problema** se encuentra cuando *(al seleccionar el input con nombre "Fecha #4"),* **ese input que tiene el DatePicker no establece la fecha que se encuentra en el input**. Al aplicar el código de muestra en el code-snippet que ofrece Stack Overflow en Español, parece que esta misma situación sucede con los inputs **Fecha #1** y **Fecha #3** disponibles.<sup>1</sup>

Este es el código usando el [editor de código ó code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/430):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Set datepicker to specific fields. */
  $("#txt_fecha_uno").datepicker({
    altFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"
  });

  $("#txt_fecha_dos").datepicker({
    altFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"
  });

  $("#txt_fecha_tres").datepicker({
    altFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"
  });

  $("#txt_fecha_cuatro").datepicker({
    altFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"
  });
});
```

```css
.data {
  float: left;
}
.data > input {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Referencias al DatePicker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">

<div id="customers">
  <div class="data">
    <span>Fecha #1</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_fecha_uno" value="15/08/2010" />
  </div>
  <div class="data">
    <span>Fecha #2</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_fecha_dos" value="08/07/2004" />
  </div>
  <div class="data">
    <span>Fecha #3</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_fecha_tres" value="16/01/2005" />
  </div>
  <div class="data">
    <span>Fecha #4</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_fecha_cuatro" value="06/12/2014" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Como pueden ver, esto no sucede con los otros tres inputs.

No encuentro información similar/duplicada sobre esta situación en particular.

**¿Hay alguna manera para que todos los DatePicker funcionen de la misma manera?**

---

<sup>1</sup> He revisado en los siguientes navegadores:

- Google Chrome *versión 47.0.2526.111* [fuente](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/OC5HX8zsipU)
- Internet Explorer 11
- Mozilla Firefox *versión 3.31*

*Actualización:* Se debe establecer el formato de fecha `yyyy-mm-dd` para guardarlo en la lista de SharePoint *solo acepta este formato.* No considero que esa sea la causa *aunque puedo estar equivocado*, ya que, al digitar la fecha en el campo (con formato `dd/mm/yyyy`), ésta se aplica al DatePicker, incluso, estableciendo el formato `dd/mm/yyyy` o removiéndolo, **las fechas en el input Fecha #3 o cualquiera de los otros inputs no se establece con el valor indicado en el input**.

Comment: Cuando seleccion el input #4 me desplega el calendario y me seleccion el 12 de June de 2014, o sea en el calendario si esta seleccionando la fecha que le indicas en el textbox. No se si sera algo del browser, estoy usando FireFox

Comment: A mí me falla la fecha #1 y no la #4

Comment: A mi me funciona bien con Chrome, cargan los datos predefinidos en todos los inputs

Comment: @LeandroTuttini, en el archivo HTML que tengo en mi equipo _usando Chrome_ falla el Fecha #4, pero al ver la pregunta, falla fecha #1 _así como dice el [comentario de Alvaro Montoro](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3211/componente-datepicker-api-no-es-consistente-con-la-selecci%C3%B3n-de-fechas?noredirect=1#comment4951_3211)_

Comment: @CésarBustíos ¿me puede decir por favor la versión de su navegador de Chrome?

Comment: @Mauricio Version 47.0.2526.111 (64-bit)

Comment: Por cierto, al datepicker se le está dando el formato "yyyy-mm-dd" pero el valor de los inputs viene en formato "dd/mm/yyyy", ¿podría ser eso la causa?

Comment: @Mauricio sera algo del browser, intentate con otros distintos a Chrome ? en IE te funciona, al menos para ver si puede ser algo de la globalizacion de javascript, con la configuracion de formato de fechas. Si cambias de fechas por ejemplo al input #4 le defines 12/06/2014 lo selecciona?  Si asignas la fecha por javascript lo intentaste

Comment: @Todos, he actualizado mi pregunta, _es extraño_, pero en mi equipo, al ver mi pregunta con el browser Firefox, **Fecha #1 y Fecha #3** no establecen las fechas, en Chrome solo falla **Fecha #3**, me parece que es algo aleatorio...

Comment: @Mauricio la fecha por defecto se esta indicando en formato mm/dd/yyyy, por eso comentaba si era un problema de globalizacion con javascript. por eso te comente que a mi me desplegaba el 12 de Junio y no el 6 de Diciembre

Comment: @Todos, gracias por su ayuda, he aceptado la respuesta de [Alvaro Montoro.](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3213/78)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que nosotros interpretamos la fecha como "dd/mm/yyyy", pero datepicker (¿o el navegador por la localización?) la interpreta como "mm/dd/yyyy" y eso causa todo. Por ejemplo: la fecha "15/08/2010" la leemos como 15 de agosto; pero datepicker piensa que es el día 8 del mes 15, que no existe y por eso te muestra la fecha de hoy.

Para solucionarlo, actualiza los valores en los inputs y ya está.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Set datepicker to specific fields. */
  $("#txt_fecha_uno").datepicker({
    altFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"
  });

  $("#txt_fecha_dos").datepicker({
    altFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"
  });

  $("#txt_fecha_tres").datepicker({
    altFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"
  });

  $("#txt_fecha_cuatro").datepicker({
    altFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"
  });
});
```

```css
.data {
  float: left;
}
.data > input {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Referencias al DatePicker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">

<div id="customers">
  <div class="data">
    <span>Fecha #1</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_fecha_uno" value="08/15/2010" />
  </div>
  <div class="data">
    <span>Fecha #2</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_fecha_dos" value="07/08/2004" />
  </div>
  <div class="data">
    <span>Fecha #3</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_fecha_tres" value="01/16/2005" />
  </div>
  <div class="data">
    <span>Fecha #4</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_fecha_cuatro" value="12/06/2014" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta claro tiene que ver con la cultura aplicada en javascript

Para solucionarlo deberias implementar: [globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize)

Con este podrias definir la cultura que javascript aplicara al sitio

Veras en el link bajo el titulo `Getting Started` como se plantea un cambio de cultura para definir el formato de la fecha

```
var Globalize = require( "globalize" );

Globalize("en").formatDate(new Date());
// > "11/27/2015"

Globalize("es").formatDate(new Date());
// > "27/11/2015"
```

Ese ejemplo deja mas que claro como aplicar la cultura y esto seguro afecta a los controles de jquery.